# VS Code not executing Python Code with Python

Tags: python

I am getting the following error messages when trying to execute some Python code in VS Code:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.keys
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.by
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.ui
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.ui
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support
```

I think it's possibly because it's not being executed as Python code but I am new to all this and I can't seem to rectify the issue. The strange thing is that this code worked a couple of weeks ago when I wrote it but I am unsure what has happened between now and then.

I have tried setting the interpreter in VS Code to all the options available and I read another post that suggested adding the following line to the top of the code...

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

...but that did not work either. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Does the bottom bar say "Python (version_no)" in the left side? You should be able to select your Python interpreter from that bar.

Comment: Without a simple code sample from your code its hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running python in vs code in a terminal with command. python name_of_the_file.py . But don't forget to cd into the right directory or use the right virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that answered.

After about 30 minutes, a VS Code suggestion box with a single click button to resolve an issue it had detected popped up. I clicked and it solved the problem, whatever the problem was.